# JQuery references moving to the Bottom of page is not loading dynamicaly added Partial View JQuery Scripts

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view which loads the partial view using the below code:

```
 @if (Model.InfoDetails != null)
     {    
         foreach (var details in Model.InfoDetails)
             {
                Html.RenderPartial("_Details", details);
              }
     }
```

In the Partial view, we have a reference to the external js file.

```
@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryBusinessDetails") // All the Jquery events are placed in this file
<script type="text/javascript">
// role based control enable disable
</scripts>
}
```

This partial view is loaded dynamically when user clicks on Add New Details in the main view.
In the _Layout.cshrml, just above the  tag, added reference to all the JQuery library and custom files.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryBusiness")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/menu")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Question:

When adding the partial view dynamically, JQuery events are not firing for the newly added partial view. Where exactly should we add reference to this JQuery file when we plan to move all the JQuery references to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Your loading multiple copies of the same scripts. You should include them in the main view, not the partial. It not clear exactly what you are doing but when you update the DOM dynamically, then you need to use event delegation for handling the events of new elements using `.on(..)`

Comment: I am using .on for the events in the jqueryBusinessDetails external file. But when I move this custom JQuery reference to the main view, datepickers images are not loading and the events are not getting fired.